# How do I do inline Razor code within some HTML?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

What I want to do:

```
<div class='duck@if (this.Model.quacker) { -noisy }'>quack</div>
```

ie. either

```
<div class='duck'>quack</div>
```

or

```
<div class='duck-noisy'>quack</div>
```

However I can't quite get the syntax right. I tried `@:-noisy` but that generates errors such as

> Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters
>   within this block

I tried also @:-noisy@ but the same error. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The <text> element will transition to HTML again. Like this:

```
<div class='duck@if (this.Model.quacker) { <text>-noisy</text> }'>quack</div>
```

Comment: yours is the solution but it generates a white space. Should be like this : `<div class='duck-@if(this.Model.quacker){<text>noisy</text>}'>quack</div>`

Comment: @ArjanEinbu I am not sure if **duck   -noisy** is a legitimate class name. It rolls down to my solution if it isn't.

Comment: @ArjanEinbu see my updated answer. It gives the best solution.

Comment: Unfortunately your edit does not work, there must be a space before @if for it to not detect it as a string.

Comment: @SLC if you write it this way as it is indicated on my sample, it will definitely work : `<div class='@("duck")@if(this.Model.quacker){<text>-noisy</text>}'>quack</div>`

Answer (score 1):

do this as follows :

```
@{
    var poo = string.Format("{0}{1}", "duck", (this.Model.quacker) ? "-noisy" : "");
}

<div class='@poo'>quack</div>
```

**UPDATE**

The below one is generating the best solution :

```
<div class='@("duck")@if(this.Model.quacker){<text>-noisy</text>}'>quack</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

should be like this

```
<div @if(this.Model.quacker) 
{
@:class='duck-noisy' 
}else{
@:class='duck'
}>quack</div>
```